# Labels have incorrect spacing in timeline

Tags: bug, design, timeline, user-labels

I found two posts where user labels apparently have incorrect spacing in some timeline events.

[Example 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/370424/timeline?filter=NoVoteDetail): The label overlaps a username.

[image]

[Example 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/65577/timeline): The label has zero spacing from the username in the above line.

[image]

Using Firefox 92.0.1 (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro.
rev 2021.10.1.40358

Comment: Yeah, this is a problem, *especially* with descenders (e.g., g, as shown above)